# Problem with adding new field to attribute table after performing join by attributes

Tags: arcgis-desktop, attribute-table, attribute-joins, arcgis-10.2

I am studying ArcMap 10.2 and concentrates on different join operations. I am working on a Personal Geodatabase.

I have digitized some polygons from a raster representing houses and have created a feature class under a certain feature dataset for this purpose. I have further created a table (not within any feature dataset) contains number of people occupy each house. I've used the ID in the polygon layer as a primary key and field named house_number in the table i've formed as a foriegn key.

After joining those two tables - I've received the attached new table:

[image: 1st table after join. I've joined the green circled table to the red cirecled feature class. Primary Key in yellow and Foriegn Key in blue]

After that I've tried to add a field (double precision) to use the field calculator, but it caused data to shift from one field to another, messing the attribute table. While in editor mode data is organized as it should be, but after exiting the editor mode it is being shifted back. Photos are attached:

[image: after adding the field]

[image: In editor mode]

Comment: Have you tried adding the calculated field before performing the join (if possible)?

Comment: Hi GeoKevin. It is not possible since I joined a data that is essential for the calculation. However the problem occures just when I add a field - even without using the field calcualtor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referring to the comment of @GeoKevin try this:

1. Add field (*densitiy*) to your polygon feature class (*Resid*).
2. Join your two tables
3. Use field calculator to calculate the field *density*. Field calculator will has access to both tables (*Resid* and *Occupied*)!

Answer (score 2):

Export the joined table into a new shapefile or feature class, and then add the new field.

Comment: thanks. I'll check it on Sunday when I'll have ESRI access again.